# Why my web service server keeps the first successful authentication to an application server?

Tags: java, web-services, authentication

I have a JAX-WS web service based on Java SE 6. There is a web service method which logs on an application server via HTTP and reads information.

If a client invokes the web service method with correct user name and password, it will get authenticated on the application server and then get response from it.

Then, if the second client invokes the web service method with wrong username/password, it will get authenticated and receive confidential information too - this is wrong behaviour.

Only when the web service server is restarted between those 2 client invokes, will the second invoke be rejected if username/password are wrong.

It seems that the web servce server keeps the authentication to the application server once the authenticated connection has been created, and then successive invokes do not need to be authenticated any more.

My question is, how to make 2 calls of the web service method completely isolated?

Comment: what is the mechanism used for authentication?

Comment: The application server is PTC Windchill server.  It uses HTTP authentication infrastructure. This is a Web server , which authenticates HTTP requests using an LDAP-accessible directory server as its user database.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but are you perhaps storing the authentication token as instance variable in the WS servlet?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You have two options - make your webservice RESTful-like (pass your authentication details with EVERY request and don't store any state information within the webservice itself or make sure that you pass AND validate sessionID between webservice and your client(s).
But without seeing your code it is difficult to say what is better approach in this case.